# I want to add scroll to multiple linear layouts in android and also want to place buttons at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

What is the way to put multiple linear layouts in one scroll view, and meanwhile I want 4 buttons at the bottom for actions which should remain there in a strip or menu. Can any one please guide me in the right way to handle this. I am newbie in Android and I tried to explore this on forums and sites but everywhere I have seen that the scroll view can manage only one child, but I have multiple linear layouts with text fields.
I am attaching an image for explanation.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="25dip"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:paddingTop="25dip" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtVehicleNo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/vehicle_no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="25dip"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:paddingTop="25dip" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtViolationCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/violation_code"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="25dip"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:paddingTop="25dip" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtReceiptNo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/receipt_no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="25dip"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:paddingTop="25dip" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtFineAmount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/fine_amount"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="25dip"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:paddingTop="25dip" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPreviousDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/previous_details"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout xml here ...

Comment: @MuhammadAtifAgha, use my answer. Its suite your all requirement.

Comment: i dont know who rated me -1, this question is no where on stackoverflow and it is also very knowledge giving. Pesimissim everywhere!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I thinks I am late here, please see below answer. its working fine and tested by me.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtVehicleNo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="vehicle_no"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtViolationCode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="violation_code"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtReceiptNo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="receipt_no"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtFineAmount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="fine_amount"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtPreviousDetails"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="previous_details"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="profile"
            android:textColor="#ff00ff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="submit"
            android:textColor="#ff00ff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="logout"
            android:textColor="#ff00ff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="exit"
            android:textColor="#ff00ff" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Updated:**

Well as you said that you wants to add the items in action bar, so follow simple steps to do this.

**add below `main.xml` to menu folder:-**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >



      <item
            android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/male1"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="action_search"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/as"
            android:icon="@drawable/picture"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="as"/>

    </menu>
```

**override onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) inside your activity:**

```
package com.rk.aatest;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity   {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

**See Output ScreenShot For demo:**

[image]

Comment: scroll view is working fine but buttons are not appearing at bottom, i want them to be visible on any scroll position means absolute.

Comment: tell me is it better to put these features in action bar?

Comment: Means you want to use the tabs in actionbar like as a buttons?

Comment: Yes i have to perform functions like profile, picture, search, submit, logout

Comment: see updated code to create a sample like you wants, please accept this answer if   helps you. so that it can help to other's.

Comment: my code will not create the tab, but it will create the button in actionbar as u wants.

Comment: sure, will this action bar open when we will click on menu button in android?

Comment: yes, only you need to perform the click event for each item.

Answer (score 1):

here is your solution

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
       <!--  Add your chail views here  -->
        <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ></LinearLayout>
          <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>    


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="first"
        />
     <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="second"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />
      <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="third"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />
       <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fourth"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />

        />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But i have multiple linear layouts having fields.

Comment: under scroll view you can have only one direct view you can do it in this way I am editing my answer wait

Comment: excellent, the scroll is working perfect, what about the below buttons, should i place these in buttons or i should put in action bar, pls guide with code, thanks.

Comment: You can use Tab host or the buttons

Answer (score 1):

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rlHomeMain"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip"
            android:paddingRight="25dip"
            android:paddingTop="25dip" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtVehicleNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip"
            android:paddingRight="25dip"
            android:paddingTop="25dip" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtViolationCode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip"
            android:paddingRight="25dip"
            android:paddingTop="25dip" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtReceiptNo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip"
            android:paddingRight="25dip"
            android:paddingTop="25dip" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtFineAmount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip"
            android:paddingRight="25dip"
            android:paddingTop="25dip" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtPreviousDetails"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llbottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="profile" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btncancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="submit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btncancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:text="logout"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btncancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:text="exit"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```